# Box plotting with respect to an entire data frame, and not individual entries in a Df

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, boxplot

Thank you very much in advance.  Here is my question. I am using R, and am novice/intermediate

First here is sample data

```
A   Number.of.Reads.Before  35453882
B   Number.of.Reads.Before  34100584
C   Number.of.Reads.Before  42248349
D   Number.of.Reads.After   15397090
E   Number.of.Reads.After   10999641
F   Number.of.Reads.After   13304229
```

So this is for a single DF_1, i have three data frames similar to this call them DF_1, DF_2, DF_3.

I am interested in created a single box plot entry for this entire data frame, and not entry specific.

For instance this code

```
qplot(ID,Total_Reads, data=trim_untrim_read, geom="boxplot")
```

The above code will generate on the X axis a box plot corresponding to each ID.  That works nice (needs some formatting for labeling… okay)
However, is it possible to create a single Box/whisker plot for this ENTIRE data frame ?

Thank you again in advance, and  I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: What I mean is the code I am interested in will produce a single box plot. not 6 of them.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
# If the data looks like this:
> str(DF_1)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 6 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ V2: Factor w/ 2 levels "Number.of.Reads.After",..: 2 2 2 1 1 1
 $ V3: int  35453882 34100584 42248349 15397090 10999641 13304229

ggplot(data = DF_1, aes(x = "X Label", y = V3)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: thank you. i will test. i used boxplot() command from another post here. but i want to do it in ggplot2. this will create a single boxplot. thank you